# Save and Export Mouse co-ordinates Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, mouseevent

I am trying to create an application using which i will be able to click and drag the mouse any where inside a frame and the corresponding mouse coordinates should be saved in to a stack or a list and i should be able to export the list onto a database or excel file.

At present i am able to retrieve the mouse coordinates using,

```
base.OnMouseMove(e);
x = e.X;
y = e.Y;
toolStripStatusLabelXY.Text = x.ToString();
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = y.ToString();
```

Is it possible to do this in a C# win32 form application.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Add this reference to code

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

and add this code to your code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons,uint dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

public void DoLeftMouseClick(int x int y)
{
    //this function perfoms left click a position you want
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

public void DoLeftMouseClick(int x int y)
{
    //this function perfoms right click a position you want
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

If you want to drag use theese;

```
public void DoLeftMouseClickDown(int x int y)
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
}

public void DoLeftMouseClickUp(int x int y)
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}

public void DoLeftMouseClickDown(int x int y)
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN , x, y, 0, 0);
}

public void DoLeftMouseClickUp(int x int y)
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

Use theese like this;

```
DoLeftMouseClickDown(positionToClick.X,positionToClick.Y);
DoLeftMouseClickUp(positionToDrag.X,positionToDrag.Y)
```

this drags the item which is at positionToClick to positionToDrag

Comment: I appreciate your response, my question is not getting the mouse co-ordinates, but to export the coordinates into a list. Is it possible?

Comment: yes you can use List<Point> points = new List<Point>(); and for saving points.add(e.Location); if you want to write them a file it's a diffrent thing that I cant write into that comment.

Comment: after adding points to the list, is it possible to view the list?

Comment: Yes of course. `'foreach(Point o in points){ listBox1.Items.Add("X ="+o.X+" Y="+o.Y);}`